# How to make an animated gif grayscale with imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick, animated-gif

I have an animated GIF which is color, I would like to make it grayscale. How can I do this with ImageMagick? I've tried using this:

```
convert image.gif -fx "(r+g+b)/3" imageGS.gif
```

But this leaves me with a grayscale image that is just the first frame of the animation.

How do I tell ImageMagick to affect all the frames of the animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [modulate](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#modulate) command instead and set the saturation to 0:

```
convert image.gif -modulate 100,0,100 imageGS.gif
```

I tested this with my own animated gif and it worked.